# HTML file pulling PHP file-> prints two pages instead of one

Tags: php, analytics, google-ads-api

http://www.freshmarketonline.com/coupon/coupon.php

My restaurant has a coupon, which is linked above, on its website. The coupon always expires "tomorrow," so that we can get customers to come back to the website every day so they can see what we are serving on our menu. I had someone write a PHP script to automatically generate a coupon with the expiration date for the next day.

I wanted to put a conversion tracking for google analytics and google adwords (so that I can track the effectiveness of AdWords), but it is a hassle to do so with a dynamic PHP script. There is a multi-step process, including changing code and some conversion value. It was more complicated than I expected, so I pulled the PHP file from an HTML file, which is linked below:

http://www.freshmarketonline.com/coupon/coupon_new.html

So, this HTML file pulls the PHP file. I was also able to copy and paste the conversion codes into this HTML file without a problem. The tags work perfectly, except one thing:

When customers print out the coupon, it automatically prints two pages, one coupon and one blank page. Is there anyway to make this coupon only print out one page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason is because you are calling in an iframe set to a height of 100%. With the body tags padding, that sets it to two pages. Why not pull in an image:

```
<img src="http://www.freshmarketonline.com/coupon/coupon.php" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the height and width for the `iframe`. Give the height a size of `800px` or so, and the width `600px` or something near that.

Either the above or, **option 2:**

Set the body to have no padding or margin:

```
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Regardless, you just need to make sure there is no overflow on the page. The body having margins and padding, in combination with the `iframe` having a height and width of `100%`, is causing this overflow.